# How to wake thread by condition

Tags: java, android, multithreading, handler

I have an activity running, of course, on UI thread and there is another thread running in background and communicating with activity using Handler post method(through looper).
When screen is turned of or application is hidden it continues to work.
So I need to stop this thread in onPause method and wake it up in onResume mehtod.
In my thread I have condition to pause it or to stop.
How to can I put thread to sleep in onPause method. And wake it up after activity is again in foreground.
I can do it with one object using monitor calling wait method and than notify on this object.
But is it good approach ? Or there is another way to do this elegantly.

Comment: Add some Code so people can help?

Comment: wait/notify is the only method that will yield the CPU.

Comment: You can pause a thread only with a Lock (They all works based on monitors wait and notify), but it's not a very good practice. I think the best thing to do is to stop the thread and start a new one resuming the previous thread work. Running threads inside an executor service can make things better!

Comment: My background thread is tied to activity it updates UI, so there is no purpose in service, as I thinkg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Android suggests using services for long term background tasks, but if you're just opening a new thread that is tied to your Android lifecycle, I don't think it would be bad to use a monitor and call wait/notify. Can you be more specific with what you are doing?

This is an overview of how I would stop and resume a stopped thread. (You may want to implement runnable in yours)

```
class ThreadDemo extends Thread {
   private Object monitor; //This is the monitor
   private boolean keepRunning = true;
   private Thread t;

   ThreadDemo(){
       System.out.println("Creating thread");
   }

   public void callinOnResume(){
       synchronized(monitor){
           monitor.notify();
           }       
   }
   public void callinOnPause(){
           try {
                synchronized(monitor){
                    System.out.println(threadName +  "Waiting");
                    monitor.wait();
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread interrupted " + e.toString());
                }
    }

    public void run() {
       System.out.println("Starting to loop.");
        while (keepRunning) {
          //stuff
        }
        System.out.println("Done looping.");
    }

   public void start ()
   {
      System.out.println("Starting " +  threadName );
      if (t == null)
      {
         t = new Thread (this, threadName);
         t.start ();
      }
   }
 }
```

Comment: My thread is just updating UI element ,so I think using Service would be horrible practice for such easy task and this thread is inner class of activity, so I think monitor would be better, I just needed approval , I thought that maybe there any other way to do this. Thank you

Comment: If you just want to do work and update the UI when you're done, you should use an asynctask http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html I would look into threads only when doing long term tasks, and you can think bout using an executor http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a good place to use a *turnstile*.  Initialize a Semaphore with one permit:

```
Semaphore turnstile = new Semaphore(1);
```

Make your background activity periodically *pass through* the turnstile like so:

```
turnstile.acquire();
turnstile.release();
```

When the foreground thread wants the background thread to pause at the turnstile, it can *lock* the turnstile:

```
turnstile.acquire();
```

And when the foreground thread wants that background thread to start working again, it can *unlock* the turnstile():

```
turnstile.release();
```

Good software engineering practice would be to wrap the whole thing up in a `Turnstile` class with appropriately named methods for the foreground and background threads to call.  I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: As I know using semaphore is just incapsulating monitor.

Comment: when the foreground thread calls `turnstile.acquire()`, it can hang for some time, which is not appropriate for UI design.

Comment: @AlexeiKaigorodov  Why would it "hang?"  (What does "hang" mean?)  If the turnstile is not locked, then the acquire() call should return promptly.  If the turnstile _is_ locked, then "hanging" is the intended behavior.  I did not read too deeply into the question to try to discover what problem the OP is _really_ trying to solve (I'm not an Android developer).  I only tried to answer the literal question, "What's a good way for one thread to "pause" and "resume" another thread?"

Comment: Oops!  I read that wrong.  The _foreground_ thread will never be blocked when it calls `turnstile.lock()`  because the background thread does not hold turnstile locked for any significant amount of time.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to stop/resume a thread outside that thread. The thread must decide itself when to run and when to stop. As a result, the background thread should check periodically if its work is still needed, and the client (foreground) thread should issue some signals about that.
One way to issue signals is to form that signals as jobs of type `Runnable` and then execute them on a thread pool. So when the activity sleeps, it just does not issue signals.

The main problem when a background thread wants to update the UI is that the target `Activity` can be closed (or in the process of recreation) and the updating task fails. The `AcyncTask` class does not solve this problem. A correct solution is published at [my Github workspace](https://github.com/rfqu/df4android). But before to use this or another solution, think twice if you really need a background thread. The best way is not to use background thread at all, making all UI updates directly on the UI thread. Of course, if updates are taken from the network, then a background thread must be used.